# Content Search web Part is showing duplicate results when i access my web application using the url which is defined inside the Default zone

Tags: 2013, administration, alternate-access-mapping, content-search-web-part, web-application-zones

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 server . now we have the following alternative access mapping settings inside my central administration :-

[image]

Where inside the **Default** zone the `http://SPS01/` is our web application which can also be access using `http://www.ourcomapnyname.intra` which is the **Intranet** zone. While the `http://...:30670` is the central administration site.

Now when I access our web application using the actual server name `http://SPS01/` the content search web part will show duplicate results as follow:-

[image]

While access it from the intranet url `http://www.ourcompantname.intra` will work well?

So can anyone advice on this please?

thanks

**Edit**
now i have noted something on the duplicate urls, now each url will have different zone .so let say i have an item with the following ID =100
now this item will have duplicate results inside the content search web-part and each url will have different zone url, as follow:-

- `http://www.ourcompantname.intra/.../DispForm.aspx/ID=100`
- `http://sps01/.../DispForm.aspx/ID=100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. In the CSWP query builder, go to the Refiners tab
2. Click the little “Show more” link at the bottom
3. In the "Group By" dropdown, select "—Show all properties—" and then select DocumentSignature. After that click OK and save webpart.

Check the screenshot below:

[image]

This should work , but still it doesnt work, then export the webpart, find a property called DataProviderJSON, in that you will find the "TrimDuplicates" option. Set it to true. Upload the webpart again.

Reference links -

[BEWARE OF DUPLICATES IN SHAREPOINT ONLINE’S CONTENT SEARCH WEB PART](http://summit7systems.com/beware-of-duplicates-in-sharepoint-onlines-content-search-web-part/)

[SharePoint 2013 Search – Near Duplicates and DocumentSignature](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fesiro/2013/11/11/sharepoint-2013-search-near-duplicates-and-documentsignature/)

**Edit :**

Looks like it's an issue with Search configuration. 
Go to Central Admin > Manage Service Applications
Then go to the Search Service application > Content sources.

In the content sources, ensure that only the default zone urls of Web applications are present.
Remove the urls of webapps present in non-default zone. Save the changes.
Do a full crawl.

Comment: can you adivce what will DocumentSignature really do ?

Comment: i mean what is the relation between setting the DocumentaSignature and having duplicates results only if i access the content search web part using the defualt zone ?

Comment: also the links you provide talks mainly about text documents ,, while in my case i have the duplicates on list items..

Comment: can you please advice on my above comments?